# How can I capture realtime request url's to a local file with selenium using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, request

I have a selenium script set up to open a particular website, the site requests multiple URL's every 30 seconds and I need to somehow capture those requested URL and copy them to a file locally on my pc.

I've done lots of googling and found people recommending browsermob-proxy but it didn't seem to fit my needs as I need to write the URL to a file in realtime. I'll give an example photo in chrome's network developer tool of what I am talking about that I need to have copied to a file.

The site is http://itemalert.com

This is an example of the links I need to fetch every 30 seconds:
[image: links]

An example of the popups:
[image: popups]

An example of the inspect elements:
[image: inspect]

Comment: BTW, do u want the href of all products?

Comment: Just the ones that show up as a new result, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help u:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import copy
import threading

global driver
    
def retrieve_urls():    
    
    threading.Timer(30, retrieve_urls).start() #Repeats the task every 30 seconds
    
    driver.get('webpage url') #Enter the url of the webpage here
    
    urls = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('pull-left epnlink')
    
    url_list = []
    
    for element in urls:
        url_list.append(element.get_attribute('href'))

    path = "Urls.txt" #Enter the path of the text file here
    
    f = open(path,'r')
    
    txt = f.readlines()
    
    f.close()
    
    for x in range(len(txt)):
        txt[x] = txt[x].strip()
    
    final_txt = ""
    
    f = open(path,'w')
    
    dup = copy.deepcopy(url_list)
    
    for x in dup:
        if x not in txt:
            final_txt += x + "\n"
            url_list.remove(x)
    
    for x in url_list:
        final_txt += x + "\n"
    
    f.write(final_txt)        
    
    f.close()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

retrieve_urls()
```

If u get any errors, pls let me know. It might be because I did not test my program (cuz I don't have an account on this website). But I hope that this should work.

Comment: Oh wow thank you very much this is exactly how I was hoping for

Comment: YW! A humble request from my side. Could u upvote my answer after u reach 10 reputation? It means a lot to me. Thx!

Comment: Here ya go sushil.